# Displaying a LinkedHashMap in a JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablemodel

I have an Order object which among other things stores a LinkedHashList (Product : amount).
I use a LinkedHashList because I specifically want to keep the insertion order.

```java
public class Order {
    private Map<Product, Integer> productMap;
    
    public Order() {
        this.productMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    }

    public Map<Product, Integer> getMap() {
        return this.productMap;
    }
}
```

In my GUI i've created a JTable with an OrderTableModel like so:

```java
    private Class<?>[] columnClasses = { String.class, Double.class, Integer.class };
    private String[] columnNames = { "Name", "Price", "Amount" };
    private Order currentOrder;
    
    public OrderTableModel(Order order) {
        this.currentOrder = order;
    }
    // [...]
    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int rowindex, int columnIndex) {
        Product selectedProduct = (Product) this.currentOrder.getMap().keySet().toArray()[rowIndex];
        switch (columnIndex) {
            case 0:
                return selectedProduct.getName():
            case 1:
                return selectedProduct.getPrice();
            case 2:
                return this.currentOrder.get(selectedProduct);
        }
```

However I understand that `Map`s weren't made to be accessed by index and that `(Product) this.currentOrder.getMap().keySet().toArray()[rowIndex]` is a hack.
This also has the disadvantage of making it quite slow getting a Product object from a row selection in the JTable (get the selected row, iterate again).

I've thought about using two ArrayLists linked by index but that also looks like a hack to me.

So is there a decent way to display a Map in a JTable without going though all these hoops?

Comment: How big is this table? How many rows? Your first hack doesn't appear too hackish to me

Comment: 0 rows up to however many products there are, so no upper limit. Probably won't be more than 20 rows per order though

Comment: Are you expecting the Map to change while this table model is in use?  If not, you can simply create that array once, in the constructor, and store that array in a field instead of currentOrder.

Comment: Yes I'm expecting it to change. To update it I'm currently updating the Order object and then firing a TableDataChanged event

Comment: *I specifically want to keep the insertion order* - in apps I've seen when you order a new item it just gets added to the bottom of the list, so I don't see why you can't just use an addRow(...) method to add each item to the bottom. What is special about the order? Do you need it sorted by name? If so then you can just use the sorting functionality of the table.

Comment: I do not need to modify the table directly, I'm modifying the model and updating the table separately. I'm asking how to better implement getValueAt for a map, not how to add other rows.

Comment: Well you didn't answer the question about what is important about the insertion order? I see no reason to use the LinkedHashMap to hold the data. *I'm modifying the model* - then your TableModel should be the model and you update the TableModel directly, not a LinkedHashMap and you add methods to the model that allow you to update it. See: [Row Table Model](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/21/row-table-model/) which shows how you can create a dynamic TableModel with insertion methods.

Comment: Again, I'm looking for how to better implement **getValueAt** since Maps are not made for getting elements by index and I have to use a hack to do it. I am **not** looking for how to modify a Table's underlying data, just how to properly display it without creating an array every row

Comment: I'm trying to better understand why you think  you need to use LinkedHashMap? You state *I'm currently updating the Order object*. The point of using MVC is to have a model. So the TableModel becomes the model that you update. Right now you appear to have two models. You are tying to treat the Order as a model and the OrderTableModel as model.  Good luck you have already been given suggestions on how to solve the problem by VGR.